# Automatically create a build in Xcode and send it to Dropbox or a server when I commit

Tags: xcode, build, automated-deploy

My goal is to allow my co-workers to test an app without having to send multiple emails; instead they can just go to Dropbox or a server and test it out themselves. I need some references/sources that can lead me to the results I want.

I am not 100 percent sure how to make this work. I found this link, but I am not sure it will give me the results I want.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Try Shenzhen. It can Create .ipa files and distribute them from the command line to dropbox or anywhere.
 https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen